# Search gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I get the following error when I do a date range search in my asp.net program.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

here is the code for the search . Please help. I also want to display only date and not date and time in my grid view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Story_number" HeaderText="Story_number" SortExpression="Story_number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Memory_card" HeaderText="Memory_card" SortExpression="Memory_card" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Story_Name" HeaderText="Story_Name" SortExpression="Story_Name" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IngestConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Story_number, Date, Memory_card, Story_Name FROM Library WHERE (Story_Name LIKE '%' + @Story_Name + '%') AND (Story_number LIKE '%' + @Story_number + '%')   AND (@startDate IS NULL OR Date >= @startdate) AND (@enddate IS NULL or Date <= @enddate)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Story_Name" PropertyName="Text"
                DefaultValue="%" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" DefaultValue="%" Name="Story_number" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" DefaultValue="" Name="startdate" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox4" Name="enddate" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="Text" />
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Doesn't it allow SQL injection if you just concatenate strings?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Im new to this

Comment: What if someone enters `foo'; DROP TABLE Library; ` in your first search box?

Comment: The query is parameterized. SQL injection isn't a concern there.

Comment: @BenJaspers: I haven't used this for ages, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Gerard What is your RDBMS? Sql Server 2005/2008/2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solved the problem of passing null to the database.

```
CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False"
```

Code as under

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
        CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IngestConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Story_number, Date, Memory_card, Story_Name FROM Library WHERE (Story_Name LIKE '%' + @Story_Name + '%') AND (Story_number LIKE '%' + @Story_number + '%') AND (@startdate IS NULL OR @startdate = '' OR Date >= @startdate) AND (@enddate IS NULL OR @enddate = '' OR Date <= @enddate)">
            <SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be appending the `%` sign to your dates. That is a wildcard operator that only works with the `LIKE` expression.

You only need

```
(Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```

to filter to a date range.

To allow for empty dates, you have to switch to boolean logic instead of using a between:

```
(@startDate IS NULL OR Date >= @startdate) AND (@enddate IS NULL or Date <= @enddate)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked but I am still stuck with one problem. Previously if I left the fields emplty it would load my entire grid and only if I entered anything in the search textboxes will the search be fired but now with this code (Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) the table does not load like before when the page loads.

Comment: You have to add handling for empty dates. I would switch to `(@startDate IS NULL OR Date >= @startdate) AND (@enddate IS NULL or Date <= @enddate)`. This should let you leave one or the other empty. This assumes the empty dates are being passed as NULL and not zero values.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your help. For some reason it still does not work. I have modified the program above as you have recommended . Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Gerard what is the exception/issue now?

Comment: Gridview does not load my table if i leave the date fields blank. If I enter the date range then the search comes out ok but If I leave it blank I get an empty grid.

Comment: It looks like you are passing the empty string instead of `NULL` when the textbox is empty, so you need to check for that: `(@startDate IS NULL OR @startDate = '' OR Date >= @startdate) AND (@enddate IS NULL OR @enddate = '' OR Date <= @enddate)`.

Comment: I modified the code as you said with Default Value of the control parameters of textbox 3 and 4 set as follows <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3"  Name="startdate" DefaultValue =""
                            PropertyName="Text" />. But still does not work

Comment: also tried this but still does not work...<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox4"  Name="enddate" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue ="" PropertyName="Text" />  What am I doing wrong??

Comment: CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" Solved my problem .